# не сохраняются действия анимации

Tags: java, android

суть такова, что по свайпу вызывается анимация, код во Fragment, анимация проигрывается нормально, но как только доходит до конца, сразу же все изменения исчезают, будто ничего и не было

активность, макетом которой является Fragment

```
interface Communicator
{
    public void playback_mode(int id, boolean status);
    public void song_operations(int id);
    public ArrayList<Song> get_song_list();
    public void set_progress(int i);
    public String get_artist();
    public String get_album();
    public String get_title();
    public byte[] get_album_art();
    public int get_song_id();
    public int get_duration();
    public int get_elapsed();
    public boolean is_playing();
}

public class Player
extends Activity
implements Communicator
{
    //классы
    public PlayerFragment pFragment;
    public ArrayList<Song> songFiles;
    public PlayerService pService;
    public Intent pIntent;
    public SongCompletedListener songCompletedListener;
    public FragmentManager fManager;
    public SongAdapter sAdapter;
    public FragmentTransaction fTransaction;
    public SharedPreferences mPreference;

    //view элементы
    public ListView nList;
    public DrawerLayout drawer;
    public TextView artistView, songView;
    public LinearLayout songLay;
    public LayoutInflater songInf;

    //id диалогов
    public final int IDD_DIALOG_TIMER = 2;
    public final int IDD_DIALOG_EXIT = 3;

    //alertdialog builder
    public AlertDialog.Builder eBuilder;

    //диалог таймера
    public TimePickerDialog timerDialogTPD;

    //переменные
    public boolean mBound = false;
    public int width, height, thour, tmin;
    public boolean timer;




    private static final String SETTINGS = "SETTINGS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        mPreference = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean hasVisited = mPreference.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

        if (!hasVisited)
        {
            Editor editor = mPreference.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
            editor.commit();
        }

        //инициализация view элементов
        drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        pFragment = new PlayerFragment();
        fManager = getFragmentManager();
        fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();

        songFiles = (ArrayList<Song>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("songs");
        Collections.sort(songFiles);
        pIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        bindService(pIntent, pConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(pIntent);

        sAdapter = new SongAdapter(this);
        nList.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        DisplayMetrics dMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dMetrics);
        width = dMetrics.widthPixels;
        height = dMetrics.heightPixels;

        nList.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        nList.setLongClickable(false);
    }

    //подкл. к сервису
    private ServiceConnection pConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            PlayerService.MusicBinder binder = (PlayerService.MusicBinder) service;
            pService = binder.getService();
            pService.setList(songFiles);
            pService.setStartIndex(0);
            pService.setSong(0);

            //загружаем фрагмент
            fTransaction.add(R.id.container, pFragment);
            fTransaction.commit();

            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    ...
```

сам фрагмент с анимацией

```
public class PlayerFragment
extends Fragment
implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    //view элементы
    public ImageButton bPlay, bPrev, bNext, bPrevDur, bNextDur;
    public ImageView ivAlbumArt;
    public ToggleButton tbRep, tbShuf;
    public SeekBar seekBar;
    public TextView tvElapsed, tvRemaining, tvTitle, tvArtist, tvIndex;
    public RelativeLayout bLayout;
    public LinearLayout main_container;
    public ListView func_list;

    public Animation func_anim_up = null;
    public Animation func_anim_down = null;
    public Animation alpha_on = null;
    public Animation alpha_down = null;

    //интерфейс communicator
    public Communicator comm;

    //классы
    public AsyncPlay asyncPlay;

    //переменные
    public int new_progress;
    public boolean skip_progress_updates;

    public GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context)
    {
        PlayerFragment f = new PlayerFragment();
        return f; 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //коммуникатор для связи с методами mainactivity
        comm = (Communicator) getActivity();

        //инициализация view элемент
        bPlay = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
        bPrev = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bPrev);
        bNext = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        tbShuf = (ToggleButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbShuf);
        tbRep = (ToggleButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tbRep);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sbTime);
        tvElapsed = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvElapsed);
        tvRemaining = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvRemaining);
        tvTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvSongTitle_TitleFrag);
        tvArtist = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvArtist_TitleFrag);
        tvIndex = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvIndex);
        ivAlbumArt = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ivAlbumArt);
        bPrevDur = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bPrevDur);
        bNextDur = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bNextDur);
        bLayout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bLayout);
        main_container = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_container);
        func_list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.func_list);

        //присваиваем слушателя
        bPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        bPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
        bNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        bPrevDur.setOnClickListener(this);
        bNextDur.setOnClickListener(this);
        tbRep.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        tbShuf.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        gestureDetector = initGestureDetector();

        bLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        bLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
            }
        });

        //первое обновление обложки/тегов
        updateAlbumArt();
        updateTags();

        //инициализация строки длительности
        setMaxDuration(comm.get_duration());
    }
    private GestureDetector initGestureDetector()
    {
        return new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {
            private SwipeDetector detector = new SwipeDetector();
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (detector.isSwipeDown(e1, e2, velocityY))
                    {
                    } else if (detector.isSwipeUp(e1, e2, velocityY))
                    {
                        //собственно сам вызов анимации
                        alpha_on = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.alpha_on);
                        main_container.startAnimation(alpha_on);
                    } else if (detector.isSwipeLeft(e1, e2, velocityX))
                    {
                        //showToast("Left Swipe");
                        onClick(bNext);
                    } else if (detector.isSwipeRight(e1, e2, velocityX))
                    {
                        //showToast("Right Swipe");
                        onClick(bPrev);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                return false;
            }

            private void showToast(String phrase)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), phrase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

сама анимация

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.5"
      android:startOffset="0"
      android:duration="700">
  </alpha>
</set>
```

Comment: нет, не понятно. Код показывайте.

Answer (score 2):

```
alpha_on = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.alpha_on);
main_container.startAnimation(alpha_on);
```

Способ, который вы используете, работает именно так : анимация отрабатывает, но фактически вьюха не изменяется.

Цитата с оф.сайта:

> Regardless of how your animation may move or resize, the bounds of the View that holds your animation will not automatically adjust to accommodate it.

Поэтому, вам нужно самому перерисовать вью, и, после того, как завершится анимация, сделать его видимым

Ну а если Ваше приложение имеет minSdk > 11, то вообще лучше использовать  [Property Animation framework](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html/). В этом случае анимация будет работать "по честному". К примеру, прозрачность можно изменить так :

```
main_container.animate().alpha(0.5f).start();
```

и обратно

```
main_container.animate().alpha(1f).start();
```